# Detect Tap or Drag of a Seekbar in SeekbarChangeListener

Tags: android, seekbar

Is there a way to decide if the user is tapping or is dragging on the Seekbar ?Because both of this actions are triggering the `onStartTrackingTouch` and `onStopTrackingTouch` event in the `SeekbarChangeListener` and for me it is important that it isn't a tap.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: There are ~2 billion Android device owners. How many of them do you think are going to know that your app wants to treat `SeekBar` taps and drags separately? How do you plan to teach them that drags and taps mean different things? Do you anticipate that many of those people will remember, from run to run of your app, that you are treating the `SeekBar` differently than how most apps do?

Comment: Why do you care at this point instead to answer my question ? Why are you judging if you dont know what I want to achive at all ? This should be useful for my design because I dont want to start an Animation when it is just a tap. I didnt asked you if you think that the users understand the difference. Calm your tits

Comment: "Why do you care at this point instead to answer my question ?" -- because Stack Overflow is a public resource. I want to make sure that not only *you* think this through, but that other developers who encounter this question think this through. What you are describing, from a usability standpoint, is very odd, and "very odd" often times confuses users. With regards to your problem, you are welcome to try subclassing `SeekBar` and play around with overriding `onTouchEvent()`, to see if you can distinguish between the events while not interfering with normal behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution on my own...

Firstly I logged the 3 Listener Events and I noticed that when a single tap happens that the sequence is everytime the same. The order is "onStartTrackingTouch","onProgressChanged" and finally "onStopTrackingTouch". The difference to dragging the Seekbar is that onProgressChanged is called more than once. So you come to the conclusion that a tap happens when onProgressChanged is called once. So a normal counter variable is enough to check which action happened. Hope this helps someone :)

Answer (score 1):

here are two ways to detect the event

(1) Customize a Seekbar get the demo code in [My another Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551736/detect-long-click-event-for-seekbar-thumb/55274981#55274981)

(2) according to [Ahmet Kazaman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4035864/ahmet-kazaman) method

1. create an interface
2. detector implement the interface
3. invoke detector's method in SeekBar.OnSeekOnSeekBarChangeListener

---

```
mSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
            mDetector.onProgressChanged(fromUser);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            mDetector.onStartTrackingTouch();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
           mDetector.onStopTrackingTouch();
           int type = mDetector.getActionType();
           if (type == IOnSeekBarChangeListener.ACTION_TYPE_CLICK) {
               //do click event
           } else if (type == IOnSeekBarChangeListener.ACTION_TYPE_DRAG) {
               //do drag event
           }
           mDetector.reset();
        }
    });
```

---

```
public interface IOnSeekBarChangeListener {


int ACTION_TYPE_DRAG = 0x10;
int ACTION_TYPE_CLICK = 0x20;

void onProgressChanged(boolean fromUser);

void onStartTrackingTouch();

void onStopTrackingTouch();

}
```

---

```
public class Detector implements IOnSeekBarChangeListener {

private static final int DRAG_THRESH_HOLDER = 3;
private boolean mStartTracking = false;
private int mOnChangedTimes = 0;
private int mActionType = 0;

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(boolean fromUser) {
    if (fromUser) {
        mOnChangedTimes++;
    }
}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch() {
   mStartTracking = true;
}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch() {
    if (mStartTracking) {
        if (mOnChangedTimes > DRAG_THRESH_HOLDER) {
            //this is a drag
            mActionType = ACTION_TYPE_DRAG;
        } else {
            //this is a click
            mActionType = ACTION_TYPE_CLICK;
        }
    }
    mStartTracking = false;
}

public int getActionType() {
    return mActionType;
}

public void reset() {
    mActionType = 0;
    mOnChangedTimes = 0;
}

}
```

---